# Datepicker issue on Membership and Contribution edit pages

Tags: drupal, datepicker

Drupal 10 /CiviCRM 5.64.2

- Membership Expiration Date selection is limited to "today" so it is not possible to select a future date (eg. Dec 2023). Possible years selection range is 2013 - 2023, where both 2013 and 2023 have limited months selection (Jan - Aug), all other years have normal Jan - Dec range
- Contribution Date years selection range is 2003 - 2013 (!) with the same months range issue for the 1st and the last year in range (2003, 2013)

Probably this has something to do with "Settings - Date Preferences" civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/date?reset=1 - by poking around activityDate Start and End offcet, I've been able to reduce possible datepicker range to one day ( today), empty the future years selection completely, etc.
The only  possible related message in logs would be this one:

```
[warning] Deprecated function CRM_Core_BAO_PreferencesDate::retrieve, use API.
CRM_Core_Error::deprecatedFunctionWarning
CRM_Core_BAO_PreferencesDate::retrieve
CRM_Admin_Form::preProcess
CRM_Core_Form::buildForm
```

Haven't seen nothing like this before, can't reproduce on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/,   what would this be?

[image: Contribution]
[image: Membership]

Comment: Did you try it on https://d10-master.demo.civicrm.org/?

Comment: I tried it and it works on the D10 demo site. Maybe an extension? CRM_Core_BAO_PreferencesDate::retrieve isn't called anywhere from core, so I'd see if you can maybe grep for that in your extensions and then disable any extension that is calling it.

Comment: On the retrieve() call, that happens on a lot of admin pages and you can't grep for it with a classname because it's [$this->_BAOName::retrieve](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/7ccb9b94fc9199ecb461a920bade3771af3c2277/CRM/Admin/Form.php#L157). So it's probably core, but I don't think related to the range problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a bug for PH* strict rule

Submitted a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27228), can you test and add your comments on the PR?

Comment: Tested, looks working, cheers.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for adding a review comment on the PR